# ATI (fglrx) Dual monitor / laptop hot-plugging

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, fglrx, ati

I been running Ubuntu 12.04 since alpha with the ATI open source drivers and with Gnome-Shell. I been generally very happy with them with only small issues along the way. Now of course it does not support 3D acceleration 100%, so games Amnesia would not play. The ATI driver is in the repos. How I use my computer:

- It's  laptop, with a HD 3670 card in it.
- I spend about 50% of the time working directly on the laptop (at home) and about 50% of the time working with an additional display connected (at work), multi desktop environment.

What happening now:

- installed drivers
- things seemed to working, save some small other bugs (not critical)
- this morning I take my machine and plug the additional monitor into it, and nothing happens... ok fine.
- open "displays" try configure dual display, won't work
- open ati config "thing" (cause it is a thing, a crap thing) and set-up monitors there
- reboot it says (oh ffs, really.... ok)
- reboot, login and wow, I got a gnome 2 desktop (presume gnome 3 fall back) and no multi-monitor...great. (screenshot: http://ubuntuone.com/5tFe3QNFsTSIGvUSVLsyL7 )
- after getting into a situation where I had to Ctrl + Alt + Del  to get out of a frozen display, I eventually manage to set-up a single display desktop on the "main" monitor
- ok.. time to go home... unplug monitor... nothing happens.. oh boy here we go...
- try displays again, nothing, just hangs the display.. great. crash all the apps and reboot...

So it's been a trying day...

Please help with a solution that:

- allows me run fglrx (so I can run the games I want)
- allows me to hot-plug a monitor to my laptop and remove it again
- allows me to change the display so include the hot-plugged monitor (preferable automatically like it did with the open drivers)

Next best if that's not possible:

- Switch between laptop only display and monitor only display easily (not having to  reboot, logout, suspened, etc...)

Comment: I'm in a world of pain here, locked displays or worse, hard locked system on display changes... please help.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Comment: I am on 12.04 with hp envy / ati graphics and unplugging monitor does not 'reset' configuration. :( it doesn't crash though..

Comment: I ended up back on open drivers. They work as expected but the downside is no advanced graphics gaming :(

Comment: [How do I report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/36315)

Comment: This unanswered question is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. Although OP signed on recently this particular question appears to be abandoned. VTC as `not reproducible`.